# Associations handling in Mongodb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, associations, mongoid

I have 2 models (Paygrade and Empsal) for 2 controllers (paygrades and empsals)
Here in the form of empsals in view (_form.html.erb)

```
# PayGrade <%= f.collection_select :pay_grade, Paygrade.all, :id, :title,  
# :prompt => 'Select Paygrade' %>
PayGrade <%= f.collection_select :paygrade, Paygrade.all, :id, :title,  
                :prompt => 'Select Paygrade' %>
```

Model of Empsal

```
class Empsal
  include Mongoid::Document
  # field :pay_grade, type: String
  belongs_to :paygrade
  field :salary_component, type: String
  field :pay_frequency, type: String
  field :currency, type: String
  field :amount, type: String
  field :comments, type: String

end
```

Model of Paygrade

```
class Paygrade
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :empsals # +++++ added
  validates_presence_of :title
  field :title, type: String

end
```

I want to make the association such that it will save id of paygrade in Empsal for field pay_grade.
But shows the related name of id in view.html.erb 
<% empsal.pay_grade %>
what association should be done in model of (Paygrade and Empsal) to get the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Empsal
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :paygrade
end
```

Comment: I did not get it . Well can u describe in details. I am confused

Comment: belongs_to will create a field (of type ObjectID) in a Empsal document, and store the ID of the referenced Paygrade. Thus, you will get for instance `@empsal.paygrade.name` and similar.

Comment: It gives error  when i did @empsal.paygrade.title(since i define the field title for paygrade name)    Showing /home/prem/Desktop/cleansvn/sep10/app/views/empsals/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Side note: always use coherent conversion from class names to associations: `PayGrade` becomes `:pay_grade`, and `Paygrade` becomes `:paygrade`. Otherwise, rails won't know which class you want to load.

Comment: Thanks for ur kind information. Can u edit my question so that i can get actually what i want. Since i am new in associations i am messed up

Comment: I think u can give this question answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706429/association-in-rails-using-mongodb-as-database   Please have a look if u can