# Association in rails using mongodb as database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, associations, mongoid

I am using devise. It gives the current userid as

```
current_user.id
```

There are many users. There is a controller name as empsals_controller.rb

```
class EmpsalsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @empsals = Empsal.all


  end

  def show
    @empsal = Empsal.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @empsal = Empsal.new


  end


  def edit
    @empsal = Empsal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @empsal = Empsal.new(params[:empsal])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @empsal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @empsal, notice: 'Empsal was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @empsal, status: :created, location: @empsal }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @empsal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @empsal = Empsal.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @empsal.update_attributes(params[:empsal])
        format.html { redirect_to @empsal, notice: 'Empsal was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @empsal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @empsal = Empsal.find(params[:id])
    @empsal.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to empsals_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The model of this controller is

```
class Empsal
  include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :paygrade
  field :salary_component, type: String
  field :pay_frequency, type: String
  field :currency, type: String
  field :amount, type: String
  field :comments, type: String
 validates_presence_of :pay_frequency

end
```

I want to make association with devise which have model user.rb such that related user can view their related data.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 2.minutes
   field :role
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need, except for setting the inverse association in the User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :empsals # <<<<<<< added line

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 2.minutes
   field :role
end
```

See the documentation at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many

With this, you can do things like

```
@user.empsals # it will be a list of Empsal instances
```

Comment: What i have to do in Emspsal model? Since there could be many datas related to one user how can i fetch data from controller and pass it to the views?

Comment: What do you want to do with the user? You are not being very clear.

Comment: The data that users submittes should be link with model user so that user can view only his data ? as id of the user comes in current_user.id.

Comment: How can i pass the data from controller to views as we code in controller in index part @empsals = Empsal.all. As Empsal.all lodes all data in the database related to empsals collection. Also admin can view all datas. Here i send the id of user as <%= link_to "User Detail", :controller => :empsals, :action => :index, :id => user.id %>.. So i shoul design like this if user is login then he can see only his data and as admin login by clickin that link user detail he can view the data related to that employee as id of the employee is passed